# Error requesting Rococo Parachain Slot

Tags: parachain, rococo

When I going to `Request your parachain slot` but every time I want to press sign transaction the button, it shows me this error `system.ExtrinsicFailed BadOrigin` .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The process to request a slot on Rococo is defined here:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/rococo-slot/

You cannot make this call yourself as the function is permissioned so that only certain Rococo administrators can access it.